# PhpSpreadsheet MimeType generate vnd.ms-office instead of vnd.ms-excel

Tags: php, excel, mime-types, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet to generate Excel (**.xls**) file.

then I realize the mimetype of the generated file was application/vnd.ms-office.

Test with two methods:

**Using this to direct download to server dir:**

```
<?php
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);

$filename = 'name-of-the-generated-file.xls';
$writer->save(FCPATH . 'extracted/' . $filename);
```

**and using this to download with browser**

```
<?php
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name-of-the-generated-file.xls"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer->save('php://output');
```

I check the generated file with

```
echo mime_content_type('name-of-the-generated-file.xls');
```

both of code generate application/vnd.ms-office mime.

how to generate spreadsheet with application/vnd.ms-excel instead of application/vnd.ms-office?

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust `mime_content_type()` to give any meaningful answer.... it uses `magic.mime` to identify filetypes, and that has an over-simplistic approach (typically based on just a few bytes) that doesn't delve too deeply into the structure of the file itself.
When sending a file to the browser, then the Content Type header is what tells the browser how to handle the file, and the correct mime types to send for Excel are `application/vnd.ms-excel` for xls files, and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for xlsx files.